# Есть ли события в битриксе после загрузки файла?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Есть ли события в битриксе после загрузки файла? Если есть то какое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует, в модуле main [OnFileSave](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/index.php)